# Android: Cannot be resolved or is not a field , possible help required

Tags: android, android-xml

This is my class

```
package com.example.payrollapplication.details;


import com.example.payrollapplication.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddEmployee extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText e_name, e_designation, e_phone, e_age, e_basic, e_ot, e_pf, e_otheralloances;

Button b_save, b_cancel , b_reset;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.employee_entry);


    e_name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enameedit);
    e_designation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edesignationedit);
    e_phone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enumberedit);
    e_age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eageedit);
    e_basic = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ebasicpayedit);
    e_ot = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eovertimeedit);
    e_pf = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.epfedit);
    e_otheralloances = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eotheralloanceedit);


    b_save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    b_cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
    b_reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.resetbutton);


    b_save.setOnClickListener(this);    
    b_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    b_reset.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.b_save:


        break;

    case R.id.b_cancel:


        break;

    case R.id.b_reset:


        break;



    }
}
```

}

And this is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:gravity="top" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Employee Entry details"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="750sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TV"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/enametext"
            android:layout_width="260sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Employee Name:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/enameedit"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edesignationtext"
            android:layout_width="260sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Employee Designation:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edesignationedit"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/enumbertext"
            android:layout_width="260sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Employee Phone Number:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/enumberedit"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eagetext"
            android:layout_width="260sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Employee Age :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eageedit"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ebasicpaytext"
            android:layout_width="260sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Employee Basic Pay :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ebasicpayedit"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eovertimetext"
            android:layout_width="250sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Employee over time :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eovertimeedit"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/epftext"
            android:layout_width="260sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Employee PF deduction :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/epfedit"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eotheralloancetext"
            android:layout_width="260sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Employee Other alloances :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/eotheralloanceedit"
            android:layout_width="350sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"/>
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>


<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/savebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60sp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130sp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110sp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</TableRow>
```

now at the on Click function at case `R.Id.b_save` : and case `R.id.b_cancel` and case `R.id.b_reset` , it gives the error `"Cannot be resolved or is not a field"`. I have cleaned the project and restarted it and I am working with Eclipse and this is the same error I get when I make the text views clickable in another class related to the same project, what can be the possible solutions? I have tried everything I could, I can see R.Java file in my directory

Thank you!

Comment: open the problems perspectivte from eclipse. It will says waht's wrong with your res/ directory

Comment: `R.id.b_save` isn't and id registered in the `R.java`, it's the name of the button defined programatically. The real id in `R.java` is `R.id.savebutton` and so on - see my answer.

Comment: thank you so much, I just ddint realize that

Comment: Yeah, those are tha small pesky things which ruin our days sometimes :))

Comment: @g00dy , Indeed , I was considering wrong with my R.java file or my xml but that was my mistake and I accepted g00dy's answer

Answer (score 1):

You have use

```
case R.id.b_save:


        break;

    case R.id.b_cancel:


        break;

    case R.id.b_reset:
```

You should use

```
case R.id.savebutton:


        break;

    case R.id.cancelbutton:


        break;

    case R.id.resetbutton:
```

:) hope you get idea

Comment: When you use R.id.button_id. thn it is the id of your xml file. and you have used object of button there,so there is an error of Cannot be resolved or is not a field. because it is not id of your button in xml

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.savebutton:


        break;

    case R.id.cancelbutton:


        break;

    case R.id.resetbutton:


        break;



    }
}
```